# How to configure ingress gateway in istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm new to istio, and I want to access my app through istio ingress gateway, but I do not know why it does not work.
This is my `kubenetes_deploy.yaml` file content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: batman
  labels:
    run: batman
spec:
    #type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    #nodePort: 32000
    targetPort: 7000
    #protocol: TCP
    name: batman
  selector:
    run: batman
    #version: v1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: batman-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: batman
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: batman
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: batman
        image: leowu/batman:v1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 7000
        env:
          - name: MONGODB_URL
            value: mongodb://localhost:27017/articles_demo_dev
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
```

And here is my istio `ingress_gateway.yaml` config file:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: batman-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 15000
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: batman
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - batman-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      route:
      - destination:
          host: batman
          port:
            number: 7000
```

I created the ingress gateway from example, and it looks well but when I run `kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` I can't see the listening port `15000` in the output。I donot know way.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: is istio-proxy injected into the pod?

Comment: Yes, I injected istio-proxy at `default` namespace when I install istio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as @Abhyudit Jain mentioned you need to correct port in VirtualService to 8000

And then you just add another port to your **istio-ingressgateway** service

```
kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

add section:

```
ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30001
    port: 15000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

This will accept HTTP traffic on port **15000** and rout it to your destination service on port **8000**

simple schema as follows:

```
incoming traffic --> istio-gateway service --> istio-gateway --> virtual service --> service --> pod
```

Comment: what's the meaning of targetPort: 80 , why add it?

Comment: Istio's docs doesn't mention about edit istio-ingressgateway service, only gateway and virtualservice

Comment: Shouldnt the target port be 8000?

Answer (score 1):

You batman service listens on port 8000 and forwards traffic to container's port 7000.

The istio traffic works like this:

```
ingress-gateway -> virtual-service -> destination-rule [optional] -> service
```

So your virtual service should be like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: batman
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - batman-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      route:
      - destination:
          host: batman
          port:
            number: 8000  <--- change
```

Comment: I changed the port to 8000 and apply it again. But the `15000` port is not listioning

Comment: is the 15000 port open in Load Balancer?

Comment: No, and I tried one of the ports such as `80` which is open in Load Balancer, and it worked. But is there no way to use a custom port?

Comment: You can open the port 15000 in load balancer otherwise the traffic won't reach your cluster if it's rejected at LB level

Comment: Can you tell me how to open `15000` port in load balancer，I change the port 7000 to 8000, and apply it again, but 15000 does not appear in load balancer.