# How to add custom port for istio ingress gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I'm new to istio. I have a simple ingress gateway yaml file, and the listenling port is 26931, but after I applied the yaml, the port 26931 does not appear in the set of ports which ingress gateway expose. So am I lack of some necessary step or something else?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: batman-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 26931
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

Comment: which version of Istio you are using?

Comment: The version of istio is `1.1.7`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are exposing ports not with Gateway object, but with istio-ingressgateway service.

```
kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

So if you want to expose port 26931, you should do it with gateway service

```
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30001
    port: 26931
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Also commented on your previous post- [How to configure ingress gateway in istio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56643594)

Comment: i was looking for an option to add new port in helm chart but looks like that option isnt present so took the service editing route

Answer (score 7):

As of Istio 1.5.1 installed using `istioctl` with the following command (see [official doc](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#customizing-the-configuration)):

```
istioctl manifest apply -f your-overlay-config.yaml
```

The additional ports can be specified under `components.ingressGateways` section in `your-overlay-config.yaml` file. For example:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  components:
    citadel:
      enabled: true
    sidecarInjector:
      enabled: true
    telemetry:
      enabled: true
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
              # We have to specify original ports otherwise it will be erased
              - port: 15020
                targetPort: 15020
                name: status-port
              - port: 80
                targetPort: 80
                name: http2
              - port: 443
                name: https
              - port: 15029
                targetPort: 15029
                name: kiali
              - port: 15030
                targetPort: 15030
                name: prometheus
              - port: 15031
                targetPort: 15031
                name: grafana
              - port: 15032
                targetPort: 15032
                name: tracing
              - port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
                name: tls
              - port: 31400
                name: tcp
              # Your additional ports
              - port: 10000
                name: misc
  addonComponents:
    prometheus:
      enabled: false
  values:
    sidecarInjectorWebhook:
      enableNamespacesByDefault: true
    global:
      proxy:
        accessLogFile: "/dev/stdout"
    gateways:
      istio-egressgateway:
        enabled: false
      istio-ingressgateway:
        sds:
          enabled: true
```

It worth noting that for Istio 1.5 and Istio 1.4 ports have to be specified under `values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway` section.

Comment: i m using istio 1.5.1, tried to find this config file under installation, but there are hundreds of files, do u know the specific file name ?

Comment: You have to create this file by yourself. This file is used to overwrite the default configuration. You might want to check this doc [Customizing the configuration](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#customizing-the-configuration). The default configuration depends on the profile you're installing. You can find these configs under `<istio_dir>/install/kubernetes/operator/profiles/`.

Comment: tks sir , the weird is i have deployed an app on k8s, using a gateway and virtualservice, using the istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer at the port 80:32653/TCP .. 404 ...  on k8s dashboard i don't see any ingresses

Comment: Where is that example coming from? These do not seem to be the default values.

Comment: Current default values can be retrieved in [manifests/profiles/default.yaml](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/c3ebc9df90464021d395792b886f1cbcf3cfee6b/manifests/profiles/default.yaml#L57) in istio repository.

Comment: For the latest releases, the link above for default `ports` values is no longer in `default.yaml` but in `demo.yaml`, found here:  https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/35b6de45318e1f52544fd747f532732aac639f5d/manifests/profiles/demo.yaml#L25

Answer (score 5):

The port setup is done in the [Helm subchart for gateways](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/values.yaml). Instead of editing the service directly, you can declaratively define the additional ports in the Istio's `values.yaml` as something like below.

**NOTE**: As of Istio v1.2 and v1.3.0, the default port list defined in the original subchart would be **overridden** by this. In order to keep the default untouched, the below snippet has some values hard copied.

```
gateways:
  istio-ingressgateway:
    ports:
      # Default port list copied from the original subchart values
      # Ref: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/release-1.2/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/values.yaml
      #      (the ports below override the default and do not get merged, and thus need to be copied here)
      - port: 15020
        targetPort: 15020
        name: status-port
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 80
        name: http2
        nodePort: 31380
      - port: 443
        name: https
        nodePort: 31390
      - port: 15029
        targetPort: 15029
        name: https-kiali
      - port: 15030
        targetPort: 15030
        name: https-prometheus
      - port: 15031
        targetPort: 15031
        name: https-grafana
      - port: 15032
        targetPort: 15032
        name: https-tracing
        # This is the port where sni routing happens
      - port: 15443
        targetPort: 15443
        name: tls
      ##=== Additional Ports =======================##
      - port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        name: http-custom
      - port: 8081
        targetPort: 8081
        name: http-custom-backup
      ##____________________________________________##
```